# Trouble fitting Gaussian fit using lmfit due to data values appearing to be too small

Tags: python, curve-fitting, lmfit

I am trying to fit a Gaussian fit around the following data using the lmfit module:

```
x = np.array([-1.36534351e-09, -1.29984067e-09, -1.23433782e-09, -1.16883498e-09,
-1.10333214e-09, -1.03782929e-09, -9.72326447e-10, -9.06823602e-10,
-8.41320758e-10, -7.75817913e-10, -7.10315069e-10, -6.44812224e-10,
-5.79309380e-10, -5.13806535e-10, -4.48303691e-10, -3.82800846e-10,
-3.17298002e-10, -2.51795157e-10, -1.86292313e-10, -1.20789468e-10,
-5.52866238e-11,  1.02162207e-11,  7.57190652e-11,  1.41221910e-10,
 2.06724754e-10,  2.72227599e-10,  3.37730443e-10,  4.03233288e-10,
 4.68736132e-10,  5.34238977e-10,  5.99741821e-10,  6.65244666e-10,
 7.30747510e-10,  7.96250355e-10,  8.61753199e-10,  9.27256043e-10,
 9.92758888e-10,  1.05826173e-09,  1.12376458e-09,  1.18926742e-09,
 1.25477027e-09,  1.32027311e-09,  1.38577595e-09,  1.45127880e-09,
 1.51678164e-09,  1.58228449e-09,  1.64778733e-09,  1.71329018e-09,
 1.77879302e-09,  1.84429587e-09])

y = np.array([  2,   0,   0,   0,   1,   0,   0,   1,   0,   1,   2,   4,   7,   8,  17,  13,  45,  
77, 182, 346, 494, 512, 443, 327, 192, 115,  62,  28,  20,  16,  13,   5,   6,   2,   1,   0,     
0,   2,   4,   1,   2,   2,   1,   2,   2,   1,   2,   2,   0,   1])
```

When I fit the data and plot it however, I get the following result:
[image]

Interestingly, if I multiply the x data array by say, 100, the fit seems to work fine:
[image]

I suspect that it might be due to the initial guess to be inaccurate, but I'm still not quite sure why this is happening and how I can fix this. I've included the entire code below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from lmfit.models import GaussianModel
import numpy as np


x = np.array([-1.36534351e-09, -1.29984067e-09, -1.23433782e-09, -1.16883498e-09,
 -1.10333214e-09, -1.03782929e-09, -9.72326447e-10, -9.06823602e-10,
 -8.41320758e-10, -7.75817913e-10, -7.10315069e-10, -6.44812224e-10,
 -5.79309380e-10, -5.13806535e-10, -4.48303691e-10, -3.82800846e-10,
 -3.17298002e-10, -2.51795157e-10, -1.86292313e-10, -1.20789468e-10,
 -5.52866238e-11,  1.02162207e-11,  7.57190652e-11,  1.41221910e-10,
  2.06724754e-10,  2.72227599e-10,  3.37730443e-10,  4.03233288e-10,
  4.68736132e-10,  5.34238977e-10,  5.99741821e-10,  6.65244666e-10,
  7.30747510e-10,  7.96250355e-10,  8.61753199e-10,  9.27256043e-10,
  9.92758888e-10,  1.05826173e-09,  1.12376458e-09,  1.18926742e-09,
  1.25477027e-09,  1.32027311e-09,  1.38577595e-09,  1.45127880e-09,
  1.51678164e-09,  1.58228449e-09,  1.64778733e-09,  1.71329018e-09,
  1.77879302e-09,  1.84429587e-09])
y = np.array([  2,   0,   0,   0,   1,   0,   0,   1,   0,   1,   2,   4,   7,   8,  17,  13,  45,  
77, 182, 346, 494, 512, 443, 327, 192, 115,  62,  28,  20,  16,  13,   5,   6,   2,   1,   0, 0,   2,   
4,   1,   2,   2,   1,   2,   2,   1,   2,   2,   0,   1])

mod = GaussianModel()
pars = mod.guess(y, x=x)                       
final_fit = mod.fit(y, pars, x=x)

plt.plot(x, final_fit.init_fit, label='Initial fit')
plt.plot(x, final_fit.best_fit, label='Gaussian fit')
plt.scatter(x, y, label='data points')
plt.show()
```

**Update:**
I have tested the exactly the same program on another computer and turns out it works perfectly there. Now, I'm not so sure.

Comment: I can reproduce this. It's probably a numerical precision issue, so scaling up the x axis solves the problem. There is also absolutely no issue in doing so. You just have to scale your results back to the original scaling after the fit.

Comment: Hiya, thanks for the help. That might be the case, although I find it weird that it's working on my older PC, but not the new one. I'll just scale my results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jan Christoph Terasa comments, the precision in your `x` values is almost certainly the problem.   When doing fits, the underlying algorithms need to make small relative changes to the parameter values to see how that affects the fit.  The changes are typically at the 1.e-7 level.  This means that when working with values at the 1e.-9 level, the changes will approach machine precision and may have no effect on the result (and, yes, this can depend on machine details).

The solution is to change the scale of your `x` and or `y` data so that it is in the range of say 1.e-6 to 1.e6.   Fortunately for your situation, it looks like you can just change `x` by multiplying by 1e9 and working in units of "nano-x".

Comment: Hiya, thanks very much for the help! I'll implement your solution and take it from there.